# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar una imagen dinámicamente con bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un modal como el que que indico en el código. La cuestión es la siguiente: Si abren el modal, abajo de los 3 botones de Primer, Segundo y Tercer año debería mostrarse una imagen. Ahora, si uds clickean en alguno de los 3 botones, la información que se muestra a la derecha (o abajo si estás en un dispositivo móvil) cambia. Me gustaría tener 3 imágenes en lugar de una, y que al mismo tiempo que cambie el contenido cambie la imagen. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="text-center services-boxes shadow rounded p-4 mt-4" style="height:30em;">
                                    <div class="services-boxes-icon">
                                        <svg class="bi bi-brightness-alt-high text-warning" width="8em" height="8em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.041 10.5h5.918a3 3 0 0 0-5.918 0zM4 11a4 4 0 1 1 8 0 .5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 11zm4-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 3zm8 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zM4.464 7.464a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 6.05a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt-2">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
                                        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
                                        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success mt-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#planTrienal2Modal"">Ver Más</button>
                                        
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
 <!-- Modal Plan Trienal 2 año -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="planTrienal2Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            
            <div class="modal-content" >
                <div class="modal-header shadow" style="background-color: #31b164;">
                    <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Plan Trienal</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="list-group shadow" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal12" role="tab" aria-controls="home">
                                    <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Primer Año
                                </a>
                                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal22" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">
                                    <span class="mdi mdi-cloud-search"></span>&nbsp;Segundo Año</a>
                                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal32" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">
                                        <span class="mdi mdi-account-voice"></span>&nbsp;Tercer Año</a>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    <div><img src="https://www.definicionabc.com/wp-content/uploads/codigo.jpg" alt="" class="shadow"
                                        style="margin-top: 1em;
                                        max-width: 100%;
                                        border: solid 1px #31b164;
                                        border-radius: 5px;
                                        padding: 5px; "></div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="trienal12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class=" shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Organización de la fundación y de la sede social. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;Contratación y capacitación del plantel profesional. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;Contratación y capacitación del plantel administrativo. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Integración de equipos interdisciplinarios.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Investigación y relevamiento del estado de situación de las temáticas en el ámbito de la provincia 
                                                            de Buenos Aires, a través del desarrollo de estudios que permitan identificar y conocer, por un lado, 
                                                            la realidad y el contexto en el que se encuentran inmersas aquellas personas que sufren alguna discapacidad
                                                            y cuyo acceso al sistema de salud se encuentre restringido y/o vedado y, por el otro, el daño ambiental
                                                            provocado por las distintas acciones del hombre que tornen inminentemente necesaria la toma de medidas al respecto.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;
                                                            Implementación de vías de comunicación que faciliten y agilicen la obtención de respuestas y resultados
                                                            en relación al acceso al sistema de salud de la comunidad afectada. 
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Campaña de difusión mediante los diferentes medios existentes (mailing, propaganda escrita, radial y televisiva), 
                                                            con el objeto de informar a la comunidad sobre la existencia de la fundación y la labor desarrollada por ésta.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Creación de una página web de la fundación.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="trienal22" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;
                                                            Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.  
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social.
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.
                                                        
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiante.
                                                        
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Evaluación y retroalimentación.
                                                    </p>
                                                </ul>      
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="trienal32" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp; Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Inicio y seguimiento de recursos administrativos y/o judiciales incoados a fin de salvaguardar los derechos de las personas afectadas y el medio ambiente.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Presentación de los proyectos confeccionados a entidades del sector público y/o privado y al Estado nacional, provincial y/o municipal. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Desarrollo de datos estadísticos obtenidos a partir de la puesta en funcionamiento de la presente fundación y su publicación. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Evaluación y retroalimentación.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría asociar un evento `click` a cada una de las pestañas del menú. Puedes hacerlo a través de una clase que tengan en común solamente esos 3 elementos (yo usé `list-group-item`) o ponerles tú una propia para diferenciarlos.

Lo único que tienes que hacer en el evento es cambiar el atributo `src` de la imagen por el que prefieras, dependiendo de a cual de esos tres elementos se pulse. Para eso usé un `switch` que inspecciona el **ID** del elemento pulsado para saber que imagen cargar.

Le añadí un **ID** a la imagen para seleccionarla con mayor facilidad.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.list-group-item').click(function () {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let imagen = $('#mi-imagen');
    
    switch (id) {
      case 'list-home-list':
        imagen.attr('src', 'https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/casa-dibujos-animados-patio-verde-valla-madera_43633-6141.jpg');
        break;
      case 'list-profile-list':
        imagen.attr('src', 'https://d500.epimg.net/cincodias/imagenes/2016/07/04/lifestyle/1467646262_522853_1467646344_noticia_normal.jpg');
        break;
      case 'list-messages-list':
        imagen.attr('src', 'https://img.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-notificacionde-mensaje_23-2147671665.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg');
        break;
    }
 
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div class="text-center services-boxes shadow rounded p-4 mt-4" style="height:30em;">
                                    <div class="services-boxes-icon">
                                        <svg class="bi bi-brightness-alt-high text-warning" width="8em" height="8em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.041 10.5h5.918a3 3 0 0 0-5.918 0zM4 11a4 4 0 1 1 8 0 .5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 11zm4-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 3zm8 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zM4.464 7.464a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 6.05a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt-2">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">Segundo Año</h5>
                                        <div class="services-title-border"></div>
                                        <p class="text-muted mt-3"> - Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.</p>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success mt-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#planTrienal2Modal"">Ver Más</button>
                                        
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
 <!-- Modal Plan Trienal 2 año -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="planTrienal2Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            
            <div class="modal-content" >
                <div class="modal-header shadow" style="background-color: #31b164;">
                    <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Plan Trienal</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="list-group shadow" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal12" role="tab" aria-controls="home">
                                    <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Primer Año
                                </a>
                                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal22" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">
                                    <span class="mdi mdi-cloud-search"></span>&nbsp;Segundo Año</a>
                                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action " id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#trienal32" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">
                                        <span class="mdi mdi-account-voice"></span>&nbsp;Tercer Año</a>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    <div><img id="mi-imagen" src="https://d500.epimg.net/cincodias/imagenes/2016/07/04/lifestyle/1467646262_522853_1467646344_noticia_normal.jpg" alt="" class="shadow"
                                        style="margin-top: 1em;
                                        max-width: 100%;
                                        border: solid 1px #31b164;
                                        border-radius: 5px;
                                        padding: 5px; "></div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="trienal12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class=" shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Organización de la fundación y de la sede social. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;Contratación y capacitación del plantel profesional. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;Contratación y capacitación del plantel administrativo. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Integración de equipos interdisciplinarios.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Investigación y relevamiento del estado de situación de las temáticas en el ámbito de la provincia 
                                                            de Buenos Aires, a través del desarrollo de estudios que permitan identificar y conocer, por un lado, 
                                                            la realidad y el contexto en el que se encuentran inmersas aquellas personas que sufren alguna discapacidad
                                                            y cuyo acceso al sistema de salud se encuentre restringido y/o vedado y, por el otro, el daño ambiental
                                                            provocado por las distintas acciones del hombre que tornen inminentemente necesaria la toma de medidas al respecto.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;
                                                            Implementación de vías de comunicación que faciliten y agilicen la obtención de respuestas y resultados
                                                            en relación al acceso al sistema de salud de la comunidad afectada. 
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Campaña de difusión mediante los diferentes medios existentes (mailing, propaganda escrita, radial y televisiva), 
                                                            con el objeto de informar a la comunidad sobre la existencia de la fundación y la labor desarrollada por ésta.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-group"></span>&nbsp;Creación de una página web de la fundación.
                                                        </p>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="trienal22" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-account-plus"></span>&nbsp;
                                                            Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación.
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Establecimiento de vínculos estratégicos y de intercambio con instituciones afines del sector público y/o privado, así como la celebración de convenios con asociaciones civiles, ONGs, universidades, sociedades, entidades diversas o personas que adhieran al objeto básico de la presente fundación.
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Desarrollo de conferencias, seminarios, talleres, debates y/o cualquier otro medio de formación y capacitación a cargo de personalidades destacadas en la materia.  
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Organización de encuentros dirigidos a la comunidad afectada con el objeto de generar espacios de formación y acompañamiento social.
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.
                                                        
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Estudio y elaboración de proyectos con el objetivo de mejorar la situación de vulnerabilidad en la que se encuentran las personas con discapacidad y el medio ambiante.
                                                        
                                                    </p>
                                                    
                                                    <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                        <span class="mdi mdi-search-web"></span>&nbsp;
                                                        Evaluación y retroalimentación.
                                                    </p>
                                                </ul>      
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="trienal32" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
                                                
                                                <ul style="padding: 0;">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Actividades de organización, mantenimiento y desarrollo de la fundación. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp; Asesoramiento integral y asistencia a aquellas personas que sufren algún tipo de discapacidad y cuyos derechos se encuentran vulnerados por el actual sistema de salud.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="shadow h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Inicio y seguimiento de recursos administrativos y/o judiciales incoados a fin de salvaguardar los derechos de las personas afectadas y el medio ambiente.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Presentación de los proyectos confeccionados a entidades del sector público y/o privado y al Estado nacional, provincial y/o municipal. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Desarrollo de datos estadísticos obtenidos a partir de la puesta en funcionamiento de la presente fundación y su publicación. 
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <p class="h5 mb-3 text-muted mt-2 alert alert-secondary ">
                                                            <span class="mdi mdi-bank"></span>&nbsp;Evaluación y retroalimentación.
                                                            
                                                        </p>
                                                        
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```